# Craft Commerce: Sort products by Sale price

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, ordering, order, sort

Trying to sort products by price.

```
{% set products = craft.commerce.products({
  type:  'footwear',
  limit: shopSettings.productsPerPage,
  order: 'defaultPrice asc',
}) %}
```

It works fine.

Please tell me how to sort products by **Sale** price?

Thanks.

Comment: I presume you have you tried just `order: salePrice asc`?

Comment: Using "order: salePrice asc" I get an error:
CDbException
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'salePrice' in 'order clause'.
[link](https://pageshot.net/qurnTPyhrYVN27Ym/originals.dev)

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
{# Catch your products as you wish, here is just an example #}
{% set categoryProducts = craft.products().relatedTo({
    targetElement: currentCategory,
    field: 'productCategory'
}).limit(10).all() %}
{# Magic goes here #}
{% for product in categoryProducts|sort((a, b) => a.cheapestVariant.salePrice <=> b.cheapestVariant.salePrice) %}
    {% set salePrice = product.cheapestVariant.salePrice %}
    {{ salePrice }}
{% endfor %}
```

For DESC output just change to:

```
b.cheapestVariant.salePrice <=> a.cheapestVariant.salePrice
```

Comment: Make sense. But only for current page or for 1st 10 products.

Comment: Why can't it be used on all products? Because of bad optimization?
In any case, `salePrice` is not used as a ready-made value from the table and is always calculated at execution runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Any update on this one? Is it possible to sort the products based on the (default variant) **salePrice** instead of the (default variant) **defaultPrice**?

Thank you

Comment: Answer from Craft support (2017):
Hi олег,

salePrice is dynamically calculated after the products/variants have been retrieved from the database, which makes sense it is dependant on user, order, and a date-time context. This means ordering in the database query for salePrice is currently not possible. You would need to sort after getting the results. You could look at using a plugin like this to do so: https://github.com/victor-in/Craft-TwigBetterSort if the default twig sort doesn't work for you.

Hope that helps.

-Luke

Comment: See also https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/14917/craft-commerce-sort-products-by-price